# Python login limit

Tags: python

i'm trying to implement login attempt system to my current code, but i don't know where i should tick it. Can someone suggest anything? I would like to give three attempts to login, if user fails to login, system will lock user out. I just dont know where to position the code properly.

```
granted = False
def grant():
    global granted
    granted = True
def login(name,password):
    success = False
    file = open("user_details.txt","r")
    for i in file:
        a,b = i.split(",")
        b = b.strip()
        if(a==name and b==password):
            success=True
            break
    file.close()
    if(success):
        print("Login Succesful")
        grant()
    else:
        print("wrong username or password")
```

Comment: your code gives a valueerror: 
  File "C:/Users/maxya/Dropbox/work/python_playground_so/stackoverflow_questions.py", line 11, in login
    a,b = i.split(",")

ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)

Comment: There are two major problem with your login concept: 1. you don't save the clear text user password. Never. You have to hash and salt it. 2. your file operations are not thread-safe. Two users registering at the same time could damage the file. Bonus: it does not work with a `,` in the password.

Comment: Do not vandalize your posts. By posting on this site, you've irrevocably granted the Stack Exchange network the right to distribute that content under the [CC BY-SA 4.0 license](//creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/) for as long as it sees fit to do so. For alternatives to deletion, see: [I've thought better of my question; can I delete it?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/what-to-do-instead-of-deleting-question)

Answer (score 3):

The better way to do this problem is by having a `JSON` file instead of a `txt` file. You can have the file in this format:

```
{
"username": {
 "password": "",
 "attempts": 0,
 }
}
```

In the `login()` function increment and write the count of attempts if the password is wrong.
And before the function begins read the JSON and check if the `attempts` value is greater than 3. If it is greater send an appropriate message else to continue the login action and ask for the password.

Your code had some minor errors which I have handled here:

```
import re
granted = False
def grant():
    global granted
    granted = True
def login(name,password):
    success = False
    file = open("user_details.txt","r")
    for i in file:
        if i.count(',') > 0:                    # check whether i has at least one ','
          a,b = i.split(",")
          b = b.strip()
          if(a==name and b==password):
              success=True
              break
    file.close()
    if(success):
        print("Login Succesful")
        grant()
    else:
        print("wrong username or password")
def register(name,password):
    file = open("user_details.txt","a")
    file.write( "\n"+name[0]+","+password)      # name is an array so only the first element is stored.
    file.close()
    grant()
def access(option):
    global name
    if(option=="login"):
        name = input("Enter your name: ")
        password = input("enter your password: ")
        login(name,password)
    else:
        print("Enter yor name and password to register")
        name = input("Please enter your name: ").lower().split()
        if len(name) > 1:
           first_letter = name[0][0]
           three_letters_surname = name[-1][:3].rjust(3, 'x')
           name = '{}{}'.format(first_letter, three_letters_surname)
           print(name)
        while True:
            password = input("Enter a password: ")
            if len(password) < 8:
               print("Make sure your password is at lest 8 letters")
            elif re.search('[0-9]',password) is None:
                print("Make sure your password has a number in it")
            elif re.search('[A-Z]',password) is None:
               print("Make sure your password has a capital letter in it")
            else:
                print("Your password seems fine")
                break
        register (name,password)
def begin():
    global option
    print("Welcome to Main Menu")
    option = input("Login or Register (login,reg): ")
    if(option!="login" and option!="reg"):
        begin()
begin()
access(option)
if(granted):
    print("Welcome to main hub")
    print("#### Details ###")
    print("Username:",name)
```

Comment: If you don't want to use `json` then you can have the `attempts` count after the username and password followed by a comma. Like `username, password, attempts`

Comment: It is better to use a `JSON` file than a `txt` file. It would be more simple with JSON methods like `dump`.

Comment: For the rest of us, can you summarize (in your answer) the minor errors you fixed? SO is supposed to be a resuable resource for other people, not just the OP.